Cells are not populating using UITableViewDiffableDataSource in UIView
I use UITableViewDiffableDataSource don't get cells with data.
Help me please.
My SupportModel content Hashable, Identifiable.
My SupportView open in SupportViewController.
My class SupportView
class SupportView: UIView {
var supportModels: [SupportModel] = []
var dataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int,SupportModel>?

//MARK: - UI elements
lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Помощь"
    //        label.textColor = .specialBlackOne
    //        label.font = .robotoBold28()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

lazy var searchTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.placeholder = "Поиск"
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    textField.backgroundColor = .specialWhiteOne
    let leftImageView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 9, width: 
34, height: 38))
    textField.leftView = leftImageView
    textField.leftView?.tintColor = .specialBlackFour
    textField.leftViewMode = .always
    let iconImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 9, 
width: 20, height: 20))
    iconImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
    leftImageView.addSubview(iconImage)
    textField.clearButtonMode = .always
    textField.returnKeyType = .search
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textField
}()

lazy var addSupportButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = .specialWhiteOne
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    button.tintColor = .specialBlackFour
    button.configuration?.imagePadding = 9
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "addIcon"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: 
#selector(addSupportButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.allowsSelection = false
    table.backgroundColor = .red
    table.separatorStyle = .none
    table.register(SupportTableViewCell.self, 
forCellReuseIdentifier: 
SupportTableViewCell.supportReuseIdentifier)
    table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return table
}()

//MARK: - Lifecycle
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    setViews()
    setConstraints()
    setDelegates()
    setDataSource()
    
    supportModels = [
        SupportModel(
            descriptionSupport: "Не получается прикрепить 
    картинку в курс с помощью ссылки",
            supportImage: UIImage(named: "clock"),
            timeOfRequest: "Вопрос на модерации"
        ),
        SupportModel(
            descriptionSupport: "Не получается записаться на 
    курс",
            supportImage: UIImage(named: "test"),
            timeOfRequest: "Вопрос решен, 7 апреля 2022"
        ),
    ]
    
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: 
UITableViewCell.supportReuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

//MARK: - Private methods
private func setViews() {
    addSubview(searchTextField)
    addSubview(addSupportButton)
    addSubview(tableView)
}

private func setDelegates() {
    searchTextField.delegate = self
}

private func setDataSource() {
    dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource(tableView: 
tableView, cellProvider: { tableView, indexPath, supportModel in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
SupportTableViewCell.supportReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! 
SupportTableViewCell
        cell.configureCell(with: supportModel)
        
        return cell
    })
    
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, 
SupportModel>()
    snapshot.appendSections([0])
    snapshot.appendItems(supportModels)
    dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
}

@objc private func addSupportButtonTapped() {}

//MARK: - Methods
}

//MARK: - Set constraints
extension SupportView {
private func setConstraints() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        searchTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
leadingAnchor, constant: 40),
        searchTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s 
safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
        searchTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 
38),
        
        addSupportButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
searchTextField.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
        addSupportButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
        addSupportButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
trailingAnchor, constant: -40),
        addSupportButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 
38),
        
addSupportButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),
        
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
searchTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, 
constant: 20),
    ])
  }
}

extension SupportView: UITextFieldDelegate {}

I use UITableViewDiffableDataSource don't get cells with data.
Help me please.
My SupportModel content Hashable, Identifiable.
My SupportView open in SupportViewController.

Looks like under the hood UITableViewDiffableDataSource has code to check if the view is laid out on screen or not to apply snapshot. I try put setDataSource in layoutSubviews then everything works correctly.
